# When sorting a Django queryset against fields on the related model, the rows go missing. Any idea why?

Tags: python, django

When trying to sort by related model `date` field, some of the queryset rows go missing.

```
cur_objs=Currency.objects.all().order_by('fxrates__date')
cur_objs=Currency.objects.all().order_by('-fxrates__date')
```

FYI `date` is not `unique` in `FxRates` model. But it should still work right?

Comment: It should work, even if `fxrate` of your `Currency` is null. Which rows are missing?

Comment: And which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL running on docker windows

Comment: rows from the `Currency` table go missing.